# When i click on any link on android studio app then app is closed,how can i solve it?

Tags: java, android, xml, html

I have use webview and html5,but doesn't work link another page.
i have many other page,but its not open. 
MainActivity.java:

```
package me.zahidul.zahidwebapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String myurl = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(myurl);
    }
}
```

Activity_Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="me.zahidul.zahidwebapp.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/webView" >

    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

index.html:

```
//just menu part
 <div class="menu">
           <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
               <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
               <li><a href="tution.html">TUTION AND FEES</a></li>
               <li><a href="administration.html">ADMINISTRATION</a></li>
               <li><a href="faculty.html">FACULTY</a></li>
               <li><a href="result.html">RESULT</a></li>

           </ul>
       </div>
```

when i click a link then show app has stop,please tell me solution?

Comment: Have you added proper permissions?

Comment: no,how to added proper permissions?

Comment: Please show us logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this permission in you AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It should work then, if it doesnt then please share your logcat so that we can help you out in a better way.

Cheers!